# Can ElasticSearch be packaged locally with Electron?

Tags: elasticsearch, npm, electron, atom-editor

I'm exploring building an Electron desktop app that would be powered by ElasticSearch running on the client. Is this possible, and if so, how can it be done?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Depending on interpretation, there are two possible answers to your question:

If you want to implement an elasticsearch library that enables the use of elasticsearch from within electron, try [elasticsearch.js](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/index.html).

If you want to implement local offline search within a client, try using either [lunr.js](http://lunrjs.com/), or its weird but loveable cousin, [elasticlunr](http://elasticlunr.com/).